# ngMessages/angular validation not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting neither a value emitted by the template fragment nor functioning validation.  My Jade template:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en', ng-app="Validate")
  head
    script(src='#{cdn_path}/angular.js/1.3.11/angular.js')
    script(src='#{cdn_path}/angular.js/1.3.11/angular-messages.js')
    script.
      angular.module('Validate', ['ngMessages']);
  body
    .container
      form(method="POST", action="/apply", name="myform", novalidate="")
        pre myform.name.$error = {{ myform.name.$error }}
        input.form-control(name="name", required="", pattern=".*[a-zA-Z].*", minlength=5)
        ng-messages(for="myform.name.$error")
          ng-message(when="required") Required!
          ng-message(when="min") Too small!
        input.btn(type='submit')
```

The resulting HTML: http://plnkr.co/edit/McyMXwW1b2Ae7kkwQ1sP

I'd like to avoid custom directives or much in the way of additional Javascript.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is happening because you didn't bind ng-model with the input :-)

```
 <input name="name" ng-model="name" required="" pattern=".*[a-zA-Z].*" minlength="5" class="form-control">
        <ng-messages for="myform.name.$error">
        <ng-message when="minlength">Too small!</ng-message>
        <ng-message when="required">Required!</ng-message>
```

Plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/kmNkfhdVOHQsstj6dpPT?p=preview

Comment: And also you was not using the correct ng-message for min length it is when="minlength'

Comment: @one which downvoted it please comment i need reason.

Comment: Looks like your downvote has disappeared. I note that the `ng-model` can be anything e.g. `ng-model="foo"` works.

Answer (score 17):

I just have the same issue and solved it. I want to share it so no one will waste an hour like me.

Please ensure the following:

**1. Load the ngMessages module**

```
<!-- Load Angular -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load ngMessages -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```

**2. Inject ngMessages into our application module**

```
angular.module( "app", [ "ngMessages" ] );
```

**3. Try newer versions**
For some reason, Doug Luce's code gets working just by changing versions to e.g., 4.11!

Comment: another hour wasted here, thanks for the help not to make it 2 :)

Comment: Same here, this solved it. Thanks for posting @mnishiguchi, sometimes the same problem can be caused by something else :)