# Angular JS ng-Messages not displaying error messages

Tags: angularjs, validation, gruntjs, bower, ng-messages

I am new to form validation using Angular JS so I looked around a lot and found one that was a nice tutorial. The tutorial can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/easy-form-validation-angularjs-ngmessages/). I know there are a few posts on Stack Overflow about `ng-messages` however I reviewed them and they do not seem to pertain to my issue.

I have installed `ng-messages` using bower and am running it with `grunt`. There are no error however my validation messages do not seem to fire off.

**My HTML is as follows:**

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <fieldset>

    <div id="number" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.clientNumber.$invalid && !myForm.clientNumber.$pristine }">
      <label for="client">SRF #: *</label>
      <input type="text" name="clientNumber" placeholder="Enter SR #" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="9" required>
      <div ng-messages="myForm.clientNumber.$error">
        <!--<div ng-message="required" >SRF # is required.</div>-->
        <div ng-message="minlength" >SRF Number is too short.</div>
        <!--<div ng-message="maxlength">SRF Number is too long.</div>-->
       </div>
     </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Part of my app.JS is as follows:**

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
  // Angular
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',
  'ui.router',
  'myApp.home',
  'restangular',
  'ngMessages'
])
```

**Part of my controller is as follows:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.home', [
  'ui.router',
  'myApp.myFactory',
  'ngMessages'
])
.config(homeConfig)
.controller('homeCtrl', home);

homeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
home.$inject = ['$http','myFactory','$timeout'];

function home($http,myFactory,$timeout) {
  ...
}
```

**What I have looked at and tried:**

1. [ngMessages/angular validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303518/ngmessages-angular-validation-not-working)
2. [ng-messages is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624312/ng-messages-is-not-working)
3. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6440
4. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2820
5. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages
6. http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html

Some in the list are tutorials while others are posts on Stack Overflow: [ngMessages/angular validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303518/ngmessages-angular-validation-not-working).

I do not understand why it does not work. All sites I have seen look to be implementing the same way.

Comment: no event is mention in your html code on which you can display `ngMessage`.Check this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694777/how-to-show-highlight-error-in-md-input-container-when-click-submit/35695022#answer-35695022)

Comment: it needs an ng-submit function or it wont go of?

Comment: I put it in but it does not work, I would an example. I tried my ng-click method on it but that function will no longer fire

Comment: does you check [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F2nC9gfafGKdsm772E1i?p=preview) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All we need to do is adding `ng-model` to our input.

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

In short, without `ng-model` on `<input>` element Angular does not care about it.

Look at working snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-messages.js"></script>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);
      app.controller('RegistrationScreenController',  function() {});
    </script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="RegistrationScreenController">
    
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <div id="number" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.clientNumber.$invalid && !myForm.clientNumber.$pristine }">
          <label for="client">SRF #: *</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="clientNumber" name="clientNumber" placeholder="Enter SR #" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="9" required>
          <div ng-messages="myForm.clientNumber.$error">
            <div ng-message="required" >SRF # is required.</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength" >SRF Number is too short.</div>
            <div ng-message="maxlength">SRF Number is too long.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I will try that, however Why do we need ng-model for it to work? Can you please add explanation to your answer. Thanks

Comment: Hey It works thanks :) I didn't know it needed it. Please add any explanations to your answer.

Comment: Cool! Happy it helped. Will update with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# From what i can see, you are missing 'when=required' in your 'ng-message' 
# This should fix it. Refer to examples below.
# 1) Using 'ng-messages'
# 2) Using 'ng-show'

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HTML - Angular Material Design
# Follow the following example below and it should work.
# Am basically using 'ng-message' to show the error message

<form name="editUserForm">
    <div flex layout="row">
        <md-input-container flex="100">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <md-icon md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-account" style="color:#47B2E8"></md-icon>
            <input id="firstNameEditUser" 
                label="firstName" 
                name="firstName" 
                type="text" 
                ng-model="vm.contact.firstName"
                required/>
            <div ng-messages="editUserForm.firstName.$error">
                <div ng-message when="required"><span translate>Please enter your First Name</span></div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</form>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HTML - Angular Material Design
# Follow the following example below and it should work.
# Am basically using 'ng-show' to hide and show the error
# messages

<form name="changePasswordForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password"
            label="password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            ng-model="vm.user.password"
            required/>
            <div class="validation-messages-error">
                <div ng-show="changePasswordForm.password.$dirty && changePasswordForm.password.$error.minlength">
                    <span>Password is too short</span>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="changePasswordForm.password.$dirty && changePasswordForm.password.$error.maxlength">
                      <span>Password is too long</span>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="changePasswordForm.password.$error.required">
                      <span>Password required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </md-input-container>
</form>


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CSS Class

.validation-messages-error {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #dd2c00;
  margin: 10px 0 0 25px;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```